# Serialize and Unserialize column data in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am newbie to Laravel and developing an eCommerce web application using `Laravel 5.2`. I've the following table structure:

`Products
     - ID
     - title
     - content`

`Product_meta
     - meta_id
     - key
     - value
     - product_id`

The Table relationship:

Product.php

```
class Product extends Model {
    public function meta(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductMeta', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

ProductMeta.php

```
class ProductMeta extends Model {
    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
}
```

And the input fields for the product meta are like:

`name="product_meta[price]"
name="product_meta[guideline]
...`

I want to store product additional information i.e: price, guidelines, etc in `product_meta` table. Is it good practice to store product_meta array in serialize form in my situation? And How do I handle this? or can you please suggest any other way to store/**update** product meta?

Thanks

Comment: If the meta data is dynamic this would be a appropriate way to do so. If not dynamic I would create all database columns, just to make it more safe.